# I need a method to move a rectangle horizontally by an integer length with a parameter of type int

Tags: java, methods, move, rectangles

The method is only ment to change the attribute value and does not have to call any other methods such as Draw().

```
class Rechteck {

    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;
    int breite;
    int hoehe;
    String farbe;

    void verschiebeWaagerecht(int xPosition){ 
       //The method that is ment to change the position of the rectangle.            
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically what is your question / doubt ?

Comment: Did you write this code yourself? Just add the parameter to your xPosition or set the parameter as the new xPosition, depending what exaxtly it is supposed to do...

Comment: The method "verschiebeWaagerecht" doesnt change the position of the recantangle horizontally. I want to know what I have to write instead.

Comment: Of course it doesnt change anything because it doesnt even try to do anything^^

Comment: btw: you should also think about writing a constructor for your class. Maybe you just left it out for readability purposes, but I am just saying...

Comment: I left the constructor out. Im just getting started with Java so Im really thankful for all the great tips :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move horizontally, you need to add value passed as an argument, like that

```
void verschiebeWaagerecht(int xPosition){ 
 this.xPosition += xPosition;
}
```